# Difference between Assignment and deep copy on a class object

Tags: python, class

I have heard about the difference between shallow copy and assignment in python,

"A shallow copy constructs a new object, while an assignment will simply point the new variable at the existing object. Any changes to the existing object will affect both variables (with assignment)"

In the example below, I have a class contains 2 variables, train_data and train_labels.

```
class test(object):


    def __init__(self, train_data, train_labels):
        self.train_data = train_data  
        self.train_labels = train_labels

    def fit(self, train_data, train_labels):
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.train_labels = train_labels
```

I created a class object, get the train_data of the class object A as initial_train_data. Then changed the train_data of the class object A to [1,2,3]. Finally, I checked initial_train_datavariable again:

```
A = test([1,2,3,4,5], ['a','b','c','d','e'])
initial_train_data = A.train_data
>>> A.train = [1,2,3,4,5]
A.train_data = [1,2,3]
>>> A.train = [1,2,3]
print(initial_train_data)
>>> initial_train_data = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I am confused that I thought with :`initial_train_data = A.train_data`, I just assigned A.train_data's memory location to initial_train_data, and as I change A.train_data, the initial_train_data should change as well. But it didn't

Can someone explain me the reason?

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: The statement `A.train_data = [1,2,3]` creates a new value, `[1,2,3]`, and assigns the name `A.train_data` to it.  `A.train_data` forgets all about its previous value, which still has the name `initial_train_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between modifying the object a variable points to, and reassigning the variable itself.

Consider `A = [1, 2, 3]`. Now, setting `B = A` means that both `A` *and* `B` point to the *same* object in memory. Keep in mind that `A` and `B` are just references and are not related to each other in any way besides the fact that they point to the same object in memory.

Now, if you were to perform `A[0] = 999`, then, you could print `B[0]` and see the same `999` being displayed, because they still point to the same object. However, if you set `A = [4, 5, 6]`, then that has no impact on `B`, which is still pointing to `[999, 2, 3]`.

For more details (and pictures!), I'd recommend referring to SO veteran Ned Batchelder's [HOWTO](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) on variable names and references.

Comment: I see what u meant. So you are saying, in the case A = [4, 5, 6], A is pointed to another list object, but the original memory that A and B pointed to is not affected, neither does B?

Comment: @Noob. So A and B are just variables (or, in Java terminology, references). Once you look at objects and variables that point to those objects as two separate concepts, things make more sense. Yes, if you change the object that A points to, B is not affected, and vice versa.

Comment: Cuz I just started to learn about Class, I am wondering in class objects, is the class object also points to the memories of the self.XXX components? So that for my class object A = test([1,2,3,4,5], ['a','b','c','d','e']), I can update one of its self. components(I don't know if there's a term for those) without affecting others.

Comment: @Noob. classes are representations of a concept, and instances are entities of that class type. Instances have attributes (self.XXX) which are also objects, and the same concept applies.

Comment: Also the shallow copy, deep copy is never an issue for an integer of string, but only happens when we assign and manipulate a list or array. Is there a rule guiding all these?

Comment: @Noob. You need to know which values are mutable and which are immutable.

Comment: @Noob. The issue only really arises with mutable types and containers, which can be nested to any depth and arbitrary in structure.